# PipeLine release resources lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am having the following problem. I have implemented a pipeline processing and sometimes I have to release resources like for example Files. At the same time my pipeline is asynchronous so it immediately releases control I am having a shutdown method in the Non-lamda implementation. I am not able to plug it in using lambdas. My current code looks like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Stage<T,Q>  {

    public Q process(T toProcess);

}


@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntermediatStage<T,Q>  extends Stage<T,Q> {


    public default <P> IntermediatStage<T,P> nextStage(Stage<Q,P> nextStage) {
        return  (T t) -> {return nextStage.process(this.process(t)); }; 
    }



}
```

I need to subsequently call a shutdown method on the different stages. The problem is that chaining them by a default method I don't have visibility on them. Is it possible somehow when I add the Stages to also be able to add a shutdown hook which I can call independently later based on the fact that the pipeline is asynchroneus ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can’t solve everything with lambda expressions. By the way, you `Stage<T,Q>` isn’t different to the existing `Function<T,R>` interface…

Comment: And IntermediateStage could be modeled using `Function.andThen()`

Comment: IT can not, because the andThen requires the same types as the function. But in my case i need transitions between function<X,Y> and function<Y,Z>

Comment: It´s not `andThen` but `compose` instead. Anyways, `andThen` does not require the same types as the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t solve everything with interfaces and lambda expressions only. This looks like a simple task for an ordinary class having a pattern like this:

```
public final class Stage<T,R> {
    static final Runnable NO_OP = () -> {};
    public static <I,O> Stage<I,O> create(Function<I,O> f) {
        return new Stage<>(f, NO_OP);
    }
    public static <I,O> Stage<I,O> create(Function<I,O> f, Runnable cleanup) {
        return new Stage<>(f, cleanup);
    }
    private final Function<T,R> actualAction;
    private final Runnable cleanup;

    private Stage(Function<T,R> f, Runnable r) {
        actualAction=f;
        cleanup=r;
    }

    public <P> Stage<T,P> nextStage(Function<R,P> nextStage) {
        return new Stage<>(actualAction.andThen(nextStage), cleanup);
    }
    public <P> Stage<T,P> nextStage(Function<R,P> nextStage, Runnable nextCleanup) {
        return new Stage<>(actualAction.andThen(nextStage),
            cleanup==NO_OP? nextCleanup: () -> { cleanup.run(); nextCleanup.run(); });
    }
    public R process(T t) {
        return actualAction.apply(t);
    }
    public Function<T, R> getActualAction() {
        return actualAction;
    }
    public void cleanup() {
        cleanup.run();
    }
    public Runnable getCleanup() {
        return cleanup;
    }
}
```

The `Stage` class is simple and invariant, but it’s actual behavior is determined by the `Function` and `Runnable` instances which can be created via lambda expression, if you wish. You can create and chain either, using a plain function only or by providing a function and a cleanup action. You’ll get two different chains for the functions and cleanup actions, thus can execute them independently.

Comment: I agree took me a month to think it over :P I accept this answer.  It is interesting solution you have written but essentially the answer is:   "You can’t solve everything with interfaces and lambda expressions only".

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about how resources are cleaned up, one could imagine something like

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Stage<T,Q>  {

    Q process(T toProcess);

    static <T,Q> Stage<T,Q> of(Stage<T,Q> stage){
        return stage;
    }

    default Stage<T,Q> withRelease(Consumer<T> releaser){
        return t -> {
            Q q = process(t);
            releaser.accept(t);
            return q;
        };
    }
}
```

which you could invoke like

```
Stage.of(Thing::process).withRelease(Thing::close)
```